# Hy my goal boot system (win 10 & Ubuntu) does not doal boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, software-installation, windows-10, reboot

I can't choose between the systems on the beginning of the pc startup and my win10 suddenly don't get recognized by the system , once I tried again to install I got an error that bootloader install failed  , I heard it might be uefi that locks down the options can I get some help

Comment: What brand/model system? Did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows UEFI or BIOS? If Windows 10 pre-installed it has to be UEFI, if upgrade from Windows 7, probably BIOS/MBR configuration. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the system is set to boot in UEFI mode and secureboot is enabled?

You may need to make sure you used a signed bootloader when you installed Ubuntu, but that should be all there is to it. Hopefully someone who has installed Ubuntu more recently can comment on what exactly you are looking for.

Assuming the system is set for UEFI boot with secureboot, make sure your Ubuntu installation matches.

After you have installed, you should be able to check your boot options from the BIOS setup utility under some sort of boot menu. If you have an option for Ubuntu there, you should be good to go.

If you are still having problems but you have a boot option for the UEFI shell, I can provide some advanced troubleshooting tips using that environment.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt know there is a boot repair , btw i deleted ubuntu and installed the win 10 from the beggining , now im tring to recover all the files that i lost.
eventually i regret that i downloaded the os for its heavyness slowness and the way she is not compitibale with the home user been so difficult to even downloading and running steam i got disapointed.